# For entity with String Id getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field exclusionfilterid to null value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am doing a regular CRUD operation with an entity which has a String Id for Primary Key
I am trying to do a search by a column that is different from the Primary key `@Query`

Also this is an existing table for which `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

But getting the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` saying cannot set Long Id Null for the Filter Id

Makes no sense to me because the primary key is set to string every where and I am filtering for a different column called `micrositeurl`

All the previous Answers here deal with only Integer as primary key so had to post it here
Have attached the components and the errors below for reference

The structure of the code is the usual `Controller`,`Repository`,`Entity`,`Service`

Thanks in Advance

Entity

```
package com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Event_Execution_History")
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class Event_Execution_History {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="Event_ID" , unique = false,  nullable = true)
    private long eventid;
    @Column(name = "Event_Execution_ID")
    private String eventexecutionid;
    @Column(name="Event_Execution_Date_ID")
    private long eventexecutiondateid;
    @Column(name="Customer_Id")
    private long customerid;
    @Column(name="Is_Target")
    private String istarget;
    @Column(name="Exclusion_Filter_ID")
    private long exclusionfilterid;
    @Column(name="Communication_Template_ID")
    private long communicationtemplateid;
    @Column(name="Communication_Channel")
    private String communicationchannel;
    @Column(name="Message")
    private String message;
    @Column(name="Email_Message")
    private String emailmessage;
    @Column(name="SMS_Message")
    private String smsmessage;
    @Column(name="PN_Message")
    private String pnmessage;
    @Column(name="WhatsApp_Message")
    private String whatsappmessage;
    @Column(name="In_Control_Group")
    private String incontrolgroup;
    @Column(name="In_Event_Control_Group")
    private String ineventcontrolgroup;
    @Column(name="LT_Control_Covers_Response_Days")
    private String ltcontrolcoversresponsedays;
    @Column(name="ST_Control_Covers_Response_Days")
    private String stcontrolcoversresponsedays;
    @Column(name="Offer_Code")
    private String offercode;
    @Column(name="GV_Code")
    private String gvcode;
    @Column(name="E_Voucher_Code")
    private String evouchercode;
    @Column(name="Booklet_Code")
    private String bookletcode;
    @Column(name="Is_MAB_Event")
    private long ismabevent;
    @Column(name="Campaign_Key")
    private String campaignkey;
    @Column(name="Segment_Id")
    private long segmentid;
    @Column(name="Revenue_Center")
    private String revenuecenter;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Genome_Lov_Id_1")
    private long recommendationgenomelovid1;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Genome_Lov_Id_2")
    private long recommendationgenomelovid2;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Genome_Lov_Id_3")
    private long recommendationgenomelovid3;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Genome_Lov_Id_4")
    private long recommendationgenomelovid4;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Genome_Lov_Id_5")
    private long recommendationgenomelovid5;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Genome_Lov_Id_6")
    private long recommendationgenomelovid6;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Product_Id_1")
    private long recommendationproductid1;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Product_Id_2")
    private long recommendationproductid2;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Product_Id_3")
    private long recommendationproductid3;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Product_Id_4")
    private long recommendationproductid4;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Product_Id_5")
    private long recommendationproductid5;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Product_Id_6")
    private long recommendationproductid6;
    @Column(name="Run_Mode")
    private String runmode;
    @Column(name="Microsite_URL")
    private String micrositeurl;
    @Column(name="CMAB_Eligible_Arms")
    private String cmabeligiblearms;
    @Column(name="Created_Date")
    private String createddate;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Algo_1")
    private String recommendationalgo1;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Algo_2")
    private String recommendationalgo2;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Algo_3")
    private String recommendationalgo3;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Algo_4")
    private String recommendationalgo4;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Algo_5")
    private String recommendationalgo5;
    @Column(name="Recommendation_Algo_6")
    private String recommendationalgo6;
    public   String geteventexecutionid(){ return  eventexecutionid ;}
    public   long geteventid(){ return  eventid ;}
    public   long geteventexecutiondateid(){ return  eventexecutiondateid ;}
    public   long getcustomerid(){ return  customerid ;}
    public   String getistarget(){ return  istarget ;}
    public   long getexclusionfilterid(){ return  exclusionfilterid ;}
    public   long getcommunicationtemplateid(){ return  communicationtemplateid ;}
    public   String getcommunicationchannel(){ return  communicationchannel ;}
    public   String getmessage(){ return  message ;}
    public   String getemailmessage(){ return  emailmessage ;}
    public   String getsmsmessage(){ return  smsmessage ;}
    public   String getpnmessage(){ return  pnmessage ;}
    public   String getwhatsappmessage(){ return  whatsappmessage ;}
    public   String getincontrolgroup(){ return  incontrolgroup ;}
    public   String getineventcontrolgroup(){ return  ineventcontrolgroup ;}
    public   String getltcontrolcoversresponsedays(){ return  ltcontrolcoversresponsedays ;}
    public   String getstcontrolcoversresponsedays(){ return  stcontrolcoversresponsedays ;}
    public   String getoffercode(){ return  offercode ;}
    public   String getgvcode(){ return  gvcode ;}
    public   String getevouchercode(){ return  evouchercode ;}
    public   String getbookletcode(){ return  bookletcode ;}
    public   long getismabevent(){ return  ismabevent ;}
    public   String getcampaignkey(){ return  campaignkey ;}
    public   long getsegmentid(){ return  segmentid ;}
    public   String getrevenuecenter(){ return  revenuecenter ;}
    public   long getrecommendationgenomelovid1(){ return  recommendationgenomelovid1 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationgenomelovid2(){ return  recommendationgenomelovid2 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationgenomelovid3(){ return  recommendationgenomelovid3 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationgenomelovid4(){ return  recommendationgenomelovid4 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationgenomelovid5(){ return  recommendationgenomelovid5 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationgenomelovid6(){ return  recommendationgenomelovid6 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationproductid1(){ return  recommendationproductid1 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationproductid2(){ return  recommendationproductid2 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationproductid3(){ return  recommendationproductid3 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationproductid4(){ return  recommendationproductid4 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationproductid5(){ return  recommendationproductid5 ;}
    public   long getrecommendationproductid6(){ return  recommendationproductid6 ;}
    public   String getrunmode(){ return  runmode ;}
    public   String getmicrositeurl(){ return  micrositeurl ;}
    public   String getcmabeligiblearms(){ return  cmabeligiblearms ;}
    public   String getcreateddate(){ return  createddate ;}
    public   String getrecommendationalgo1(){ return  recommendationalgo1 ;}
    public   String getrecommendationalgo2(){ return  recommendationalgo2 ;}
    public   String getrecommendationalgo3(){ return  recommendationalgo3 ;}
    public   String getrecommendationalgo4(){ return  recommendationalgo4 ;}
    public   String getrecommendationalgo5(){ return  recommendationalgo5 ;}
    public   String getrecommendationalgo6(){ return  recommendationalgo6 ;}
    public  void seteventexecutionid( String eventexecutionid ){ this.eventexecutionid=eventexecutionid;}
    public  void seteventid( long eventid ){ this.eventid=eventid;}
    public  void seteventexecutiondateid( long eventexecutiondateid ){ this.eventexecutiondateid=eventexecutiondateid;}
    public  void setcustomerid( long customerid ){ this.customerid=customerid;}
    public  void setistarget( String istarget ){ this.istarget=istarget;}
    public  void setexclusionfilterid( long exclusionfilterid ){ this.exclusionfilterid=exclusionfilterid;}
    public  void setcommunicationtemplateid( long communicationtemplateid ){ this.communicationtemplateid=communicationtemplateid;}
    public  void setcommunicationchannel( String communicationchannel ){ this.communicationchannel=communicationchannel;}
    public  void setmessage( String message ){ this.message=message;}
    public  void setemailmessage( String emailmessage ){ this.emailmessage=emailmessage;}
    public  void setsmsmessage( String smsmessage ){ this.smsmessage=smsmessage;}
    public  void setpnmessage( String pnmessage ){ this.pnmessage=pnmessage;}
    public  void setwhatsappmessage( String whatsappmessage ){ this.whatsappmessage=whatsappmessage;}
    public  void setincontrolgroup( String incontrolgroup ){ this.incontrolgroup=incontrolgroup;}
    public  void setineventcontrolgroup( String ineventcontrolgroup ){ this.ineventcontrolgroup=ineventcontrolgroup;}
    public  void setltcontrolcoversresponsedays( String ltcontrolcoversresponsedays ){ this.ltcontrolcoversresponsedays=ltcontrolcoversresponsedays;}
    public  void setstcontrolcoversresponsedays( String stcontrolcoversresponsedays ){ this.stcontrolcoversresponsedays=stcontrolcoversresponsedays;}
    public  void setoffercode( String offercode ){ this.offercode=offercode;}
    public  void setgvcode( String gvcode ){ this.gvcode=gvcode;}
    public  void setevouchercode( String evouchercode ){ this.evouchercode=evouchercode;}
    public  void setbookletcode( String bookletcode ){ this.bookletcode=bookletcode;}
    public  void setismabevent( long ismabevent ){ this.ismabevent=ismabevent;}
    public  void setcampaignkey( String campaignkey ){ this.campaignkey=campaignkey;}
    public  void setsegmentid( long segmentid ){ this.segmentid=segmentid;}
    public  void setrevenuecenter( String revenuecenter ){ this.revenuecenter=revenuecenter;}
    public  void setrecommendationgenomelovid1( long recommendationgenomelovid1 ){ this.recommendationgenomelovid1=recommendationgenomelovid1;}
    public  void setrecommendationgenomelovid2( long recommendationgenomelovid2 ){ this.recommendationgenomelovid2=recommendationgenomelovid2;}
    public  void setrecommendationgenomelovid3( long recommendationgenomelovid3 ){ this.recommendationgenomelovid3=recommendationgenomelovid3;}
    public  void setrecommendationgenomelovid4( long recommendationgenomelovid4 ){ this.recommendationgenomelovid4=recommendationgenomelovid4;}
    public  void setrecommendationgenomelovid5( long recommendationgenomelovid5 ){ this.recommendationgenomelovid5=recommendationgenomelovid5;}
    public  void setrecommendationgenomelovid6( long recommendationgenomelovid6 ){ this.recommendationgenomelovid6=recommendationgenomelovid6;}
    public  void setrecommendationproductid1( long recommendationproductid1 ){ this.recommendationproductid1=recommendationproductid1;}
    public  void setrecommendationproductid2( long recommendationproductid2 ){ this.recommendationproductid2=recommendationproductid2;}
    public  void setrecommendationproductid3( long recommendationproductid3 ){ this.recommendationproductid3=recommendationproductid3;}
    public  void setrecommendationproductid4( long recommendationproductid4 ){ this.recommendationproductid4=recommendationproductid4;}
    public  void setrecommendationproductid5( long recommendationproductid5 ){ this.recommendationproductid5=recommendationproductid5;}
    public  void setrecommendationproductid6( long recommendationproductid6 ){ this.recommendationproductid6=recommendationproductid6;}
    public  void setrunmode( String runmode ){ this.runmode=runmode;}
    public  void setmicrositeurl( String micrositeurl ){ this.micrositeurl=micrositeurl;}
    public  void setcmabeligiblearms( String cmabeligiblearms ){ this.cmabeligiblearms=cmabeligiblearms;}
    public  void setcreateddate( String createddate ){ this.createddate=createddate;}
    public  void setrecommendationalgo1( String recommendationalgo1 ){ this.recommendationalgo1=recommendationalgo1;}
    public  void setrecommendationalgo2( String recommendationalgo2 ){ this.recommendationalgo2=recommendationalgo2;}
    public  void setrecommendationalgo3( String recommendationalgo3 ){ this.recommendationalgo3=recommendationalgo3;}
    public  void setrecommendationalgo4( String recommendationalgo4 ){ this.recommendationalgo4=recommendationalgo4;}
    public  void setrecommendationalgo5( String recommendationalgo5 ){ this.recommendationalgo5=recommendationalgo5;}
    public  void setrecommendationalgo6( String recommendationalgo6 ){ this.recommendationalgo6=recommendationalgo6;}

}
```

Repository

```
package com.example.springbootcrudexample3.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Execution_History;

public interface Event_Execution_Repository  extends JpaRepository<Event_Execution_History,Long>{
    
    @Query("SELECT p FROM  Event_Execution_History p WHERE p.micrositeurl LIKE %?1%")
    List<Event_Execution_History> search(String micrositeurl);

}
```

Controller

```
package com.example.springbootcrudexample3.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Execution_History;
import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Master;
import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.service.Event_Execution_Service;
import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.service.Event_Service;

@RestController
public class Event_Controller  extends HttpServlet{
    @Autowired
    private Event_Service service;
    
    @Autowired
    private Event_Execution_Service eeh_service;
    
    
    @Autowired
    private FileReaderUtility file;

    -----
    Other Methods
    ------

    
    @GetMapping("/eventHistory/{id}")
    public List<Event_Execution_History>  getEventHistoryByStringId(@PathVariable String id) {
        return eeh_service.getEventHistoryById(id);
    }
    

}
```

Service

```
package com.example.springbootcrudexample3.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Execution_History;
import com.example.springbootcrudexample3.repository.Event_Execution_Repository;
@Service
public class Event_Execution_Service {
    
    @Autowired
    private Event_Execution_Repository event_repository ;
    // Save Event History
    public Event_Execution_History saveEventHistory(Event_Execution_History event_history) {
        return event_repository.save(event_history);
    }
    
    public List<Event_Execution_History> saveEventHistorys(List<Event_Execution_History> event_historys) {
        return event_repository.saveAll(event_historys);
    }
    
    // Get Event History
    public List<Event_Execution_History> getEventHistorys(){
        return event_repository.findAll();
    }
    public List<Event_Execution_History> getEventHistoryById(String id){
        return event_repository.search(id);
    }   
}
```

POM XML

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Execution_History.exclusionfilterid to null value
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:80) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:799) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:681) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5252) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntityFromEntityEntryLoadedState(TwoPhaseLoad.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1201) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1009) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
```

EDIT 1

As mentioned by @pengo
I Changed the `long` to `Long` in `Entity` class
now getting the following details in the log

Its showing a status 500 error and this is coming up in the logs

API Call made
`curl -i -X https://localhost:8080/eventHistory/B333H9 -H 'Content-Type:application/json'`

LOGS

```
2022-10-11 12:05:49.061 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public java.util.List<com.example.springbootcrudexample3.entity.Event_Execution_History> com.example.springbootcrudexample3.controller.Event_Controller.getEventHistoryByStringId(java.lang.String): Required URI template variable 'micrositeurl' for method parameter type String is not present
2022-10-11 12:05:49.061  WARN 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 'micrositeurl' for method parameter type String is not present]
2022-10-11 12:05:49.062 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-10-11 12:05:49.062 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
2022-10-11 12:05:49.062 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-10-11 12:05:49.063 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2022-10-11 12:05:49.063 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-10-11 12:05:49.064 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-10-11 12:05:49.064 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue Oct 11 12:05:49 IST 2022, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, path=/eventHistory (truncated)...]
2022-10-11 12:05:49.065 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-10-11 12:05:49.065 DEBUG 132627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

EDIT 2

I got where the issue was happening post edit 1
Had to mention in the GetMapping the @PathVariable that we should have specifically needed

```
@GetMapping("/eventHistory/{micrositeurl}")
    public List<Event_Execution_History>  getEventHistoryByStringId(@PathVariable("micrositeurl") String micrositeurl ) {
        return eeh_service.getEventHistoryById(micrositeurl);
    }
```

Now can fetch what was required

Comment: Do you have a row in your database with a `null` value for `exclusionfilterid`? As you've made the field a `long` that column should be `NOT NULL`

Comment: No Null values in either the Primary Key or the FilterId

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use boxxing type `Long` ranther than `long` in Entity class and try again.

The following is a simple test, please refer to.

**use basic type**

got the same error as the above.

[image]

**use boxxing type**

[image]

Comment: I did this , its throwing an HTTP 500 error still but getting a warning now

```
```